# Remove SU after unroot

Tags: rooting, root-access, unrooting

I lost root access after an update (I'm totally android illiterate).
 I tried to re-root but Stump Root thinks that I'm already rooted because `/system/xbin/su` exists.

How can I remove `/system/xbin/su` so that I can run Stump Root and re-root?

Comment: if /system/xbin/su exists, then you did not lose root. That is root.

Comment: All root checker apps state that they have no root access, and SuperSU says "There is no SU binary installed, and cannot install it." The T-Mobile update caused me to lose root but did not remove the files.

Comment: It's most likely that the update reset the permissions on that file so it isn't being executed properly. If you connect the device to a computer with the ADB drivers installed, and run `adb shell su` do you get an error message?

Comment: It's been years, I've got a new phone since then. Thanks though :)